# How do I get git to ask me for my password

Tags: git, credentials

So I have git setup to cache my credentials for 5 minutes....this is all fine and good, but that only solves part of my problem...

So I have a script that does something like this:

```
rmdir -rf repo1
rmdir -rf repo2  # These operations take ~2 minutes
rmdir -rf repo3

git clone path\to\repo1  # Only now does it ask me for my password
git clone path\to\repo2
git clone path\to\repo3

# build it
```

So currently I am sitting on my bum for 2 minutes waiting for git to ask me to type my password in......

What I really want is to trigger some command in git that will force git to ask me my password and cache my credentials for the length of the script......Is this possible:

```
git ask_me_my_password domain

rmdir -rf repo1
rmdir -rf repo2  # These operations take ~2 minutes
rmdir -rf repo3

git clone path\to\repo1  # Only now does it ask me for my password
git clone path\to\repo2
git clone path\to\repo3

# build it
```

Comment: Why do you need the git credentials to remove a repo?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I want git to ask me my credentials before I remove a big repo so that when I run this script it asks me for my credentials at the beginning and not when I clone the repo later in the script.....

Comment: There is the git credentials api https://git-scm.com/docs/api-credentials, but you should probably rethink why you need to do this. Why are you deleting a repo and then re-cloning it?

Comment: I may be naive, but can't the repos just be moved to another local directory? And then deleted in the background? That should reach the first clone promptly.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using the `git-credential-cache`.

> This command caches credentials in memory for use by future Git programs. The stored credentials never touch the disk, and are forgotten after a configurable timeout. The cache is accessible over a Unix domain socket, restricted to the current user by filesystem permissions.

The command can be used as follows:
`$ git config credential.helper 'cache [<options>]`

---

For example, if you'd like to invalidate your credentials after five minutes, you can provide options via the credential.helper configuration variable:

`$ git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=300'`

---

Learn more here:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache

Comment: Yes I have already done this (as stated in the question), how do ask git to ask me for my credentials before preforming an expensive operation?